# How to iterate over an object from an SNMP device and create a readable output using predefined rules

Tags: javascript, node.js, snmp, mib

I have the following JSON out of an SNMP device:

```
mib = [
    "1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1": {
        "1.1": {
            "3": "1",
            "5": "3",
            "6": "Cyan Toner Cartridge, WorkCentre 6505N",
            "8": "2000",
            "9": "800"
        },
        "1.2": {
            "3": "2",
            "5": "3",
            "6": "Magenta Toner Cartridge, WorkCentre 6505N",
            "8": "1000",
            "9": "400"
        },
        "1.5": {
            "3": "0",
            "5": "9",
            "6": "Imaging Unit, WorkCentre 6505N",
            "8": "24000",
            "9": "24000"
        }
    },
    "1.3.6.1.2.1.43.12.1": {
        "1.1": {
            "4": "cyan"
        },
        "1.2": {
            "4": "magenta"
        }
    }
]
```

the result I want out of it is this:

```
device["markerSupplies"]: [
    0: {
        color: "cyan",
        type: "toner",
        description: "Cyan Toner Cartridge, WorkCentre 6505N",
        capacity: "2000",
        value: "800"
    },
    1: {
        color: "magenta",
        type: "toner",
        description: "Magenta Toner Cartridge, WorkCentre 6505N",
        capacity: "1000",
        value: "400"
    },
    2: {
        color: "",
        type: "opc",
        description: "Imaging Unit, WorkCentre 6505N",
        capacity: "24000",
        value: "24000"
    },
]
```

"1.1", "1.2"... are just indexes I have information about what's going inside of them.
every property inside of them called a column and is corresponding to its index.

I know the following about the columns of each table:

```
1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1
    3   the color index inside 1.3.6.1.2.1.43.12.1
    5
        3   "toner"
        9   "opc"
    6   description
    8   capacity
    9   level

1.3.6.1.2.1.43.12.1
    4   color name
```

how can I create a JSON information object that using a javascript code I can iterate over the JSON from the device
and create the output result I showed above?

Comment: how reliable are the keys, like `1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1`?

Comment: using the printer mib I know that 1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1 is prtMarkerSuppliesTable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use some helper variables for color and type and iterate over the keys to build a new array.

```js
var mib = { "1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1": { "1.1": { 3: "1", 5: "3", 6: "Cyan Toner Cartridge, WorkCentre 6505N", 8: "2000", 9: "800" }, "1.2": { 3: "2", 5: "3", 6: "Magenta Toner Cartridge, WorkCentre 6505N", 8: "1000", 9: "400" }, "1.5": { 3: "0", 5: "9", 6: "Imaging Unit, WorkCentre 6505N", 8: "24000", 9: "24000" } }, "1.3.6.1.2.1.43.12.1": { "1.1": { 4: "cyan" }, "1.2": { 4: "magenta" } } },
    cols = { 3: 'color', 5: 'type', 6: 'description', 8: 'capacity', 9: 'level' },
    types = { 3: 'toner', 9: 'opc' },
    markerSupplies = mib['1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1'],
    colors = mib['1.3.6.1.2.1.43.12.1'],
    result = Object.keys(markerSupplies).map(function (k) {
        var o = {};
        Object.keys(cols).forEach(function (c) {
            if (c === '3') {
                o[cols[c]] = (colors[k] || {})['4'] || '';
                return;
            }
            if (c === '5') {
                o[cols[c]] = types[markerSupplies[k][c]] || '';
                return;
            }
            o[cols[c]] = markerSupplies[k][c] || '';

        });
        return o;
    });

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi Nina! I got very far with this answer and now I have a similar problem that needs to be addressed a little differently I hope you can help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38790637/how-to-iterate-over-an-object-and-create-an-output-using-some-rules-i-define